# Mule ESB CXF exception handeling

Tags: exception, cxf, mule, fuseesb, jbossfuse

I'm using the following XML in mule communication using jaxws-client inside http outbound flow (POJO is the output from outbound Jaxws Client).

for sure generating WS code using wsdl2java plugin in maven , the generated code has class for exception coming from WS the class is :

com.nsn.ossbss.charge_once.wsdl.entity.tis.wsdl._1.TisException

for sure http response is 500 when we got SOAPFault after the WS raised this exception

```
com.nsn.ossbss.charge_once.wsdl.entity.tis.wsdl._1.TisException

INFO  2012-11-08 11:08:08,008 [[cxf].TCP_C_L.receiver.02] org.mule.transport.http.HttpClientMessageDispatcher: Received a redirect, but followRedirects=false. Response code: 500 Server Error
ERROR 2012-11-08 11:08:13,008 [[cxf].TCP_C_L.receiver.02] org.mule.exception.CatchMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : error. Failed to route event via endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor. Message payload is of type: PostMethod
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. error (com.nsn.ossbss.charge_once.wsdl.entity.tis.wsdl._1.TisException)
  sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl:-2 (null)
2. error. Failed to route event via endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor. Message payload is of type: PostMethod (org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException)
  org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor:148 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transport/DispatchException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
com.nsn.ossbss.charge_once.wsdl.entity.tis.wsdl._1.TisException: error
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************

INFO  2012-11-08 11:08:13,009 [[cxf].TCP_C_L.receiver.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod@d02649
INFO  2012-11-08 11:08:13,010 [[cxf].TCP_C_L.receiver.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod@d02649
```

I'm getting the above error when handeling excpetion using :

```
<catch-exception-strategy>
            <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
            <transformer ref="ByteArrayToString" />
            <append-string-transformer message="&#xD;&#xA;" />
            <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
        </catch-exception-strategy>
```

for sure I need to handle the exception same as apache camel , I need to specify to mule the exception and mule should not raised the above exception in the console as it would be handled by XML configuration .

the type of the incoming messages from jaxWs-client outbound is

org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod@d02649

How can i manage to make Mule ESB understand the WS exception , I tried this

and it didnt work as well .

Can you please advise .

in Fuse ESB i did it like this :

```
<onException>
<exception>com.nsn.ossbss.charge_once.wsdl.entity.tis.wsdl._1.TisException</exception>  
            <handled>
                <constant>true</constant>
            </handled>
            <to uri="log:test" />
            <setBody>

                <simple>${exception.getFaultInfo}</simple>

            </setBody>
            <to uri="log:exception" />
            <convertBodyTo      type="com.nsn.ossbss.charge_once.wsdl.entity.tis.xsd._1.FaultMessage" />
            <marshal ref="decExc" />
            <convertBodyTo type="String" />
            <bean ref="nulladd" />
        </onException>
```

how can i make the same in Mule ESB .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm" xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file"
    xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" xmlns:tcp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tcp"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns:cxf="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:core="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="EE-3.3.0"
    xmlns:script="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/current/mule-vm.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/3.2/mule-scripting.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tcp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tcp/current/mule-tcp.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf/current/mule-cxf.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd ">
    <spring:beans>
        <spring:bean name="samlCallbackHandler"
            class="com.mulesoft.mule.example.security.SAMLCallbackHandler" id="samlCallbackHandler" />
    </spring:beans>




    <sub-flow name="Jaxws" doc:name="Jaxws">
        <cxf:jaxws-client operation="ExecuteCommand"
            serviceClass="com.nsn.ossbss.charge_once.wsdl.entity.tis.wsdl._1.TisInterface"
            doc:name="UsernameToken SOAP client">
            <!-- <cxf:ws-security> <cxf:ws-config> <cxf:property key="action" value="UsernameToken 
                Timestamp" /> <cxf:property key="user" value="joe" /> <cxf:property key="passwordCallbackClass" 
                value="com.mulesoft.mule.example.security.PasswordCallback" /> <cxf:property 
                key="mustUnderstand" value="false" /> </cxf:ws-config> </cxf:ws-security> -->
        </cxf:jaxws-client>
    </sub-flow>

    <sub-flow name="usernameToken1" doc:name="usernameToken1">
        <!-- <cxf:jaxws-client operation="ExecuteCommand" serviceClass="com.nsn.ossbss.charge_once.wsdl.entity.tis.wsdl._1.TisInterface" 
            doc:name="UsernameToken SOAP client"> <cxf:ws-security> <cxf:ws-config> <cxf:property 
            key="action" value="UsernameToken Timestamp" /> <cxf:property key="user" 
            value="joe" /> <cxf:property key="passwordCallbackClass" value="com.mulesoft.mule.example.security.PasswordCallback" 
            /> <cxf:property key="mustUnderstand" value="false" /> </cxf:ws-config> </cxf:ws-security> 
            </cxf:jaxws-client> -->
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
            host="localhost" port="8899" path="cxf/services"
            doc:name="Invoke NSNusernameToken Web Service">
            <cxf:jaxws-client operation="ExecuteCommand"
                serviceClass="com.nsn.ossbss.charge_once.wsdl.entity.tis.wsdl._1.TisInterface"
                doc:name="UsernameToken SOAP client">
                <cxf:ws-security>
                    <cxf:ws-config>
                        <cxf:property key="action" value="UsernameToken Timestamp" />
                        <cxf:property key="user" value="joe" />
                        <cxf:property key="passwordCallbackClass"
                            value="com.mulesoft.mule.example.security.PasswordCallback" />
                        <cxf:property key="mustUnderstand" value="false" />
                    </cxf:ws-config>
                </cxf:ws-security>
                <cxf:inInterceptors />
                <cxf:outInterceptors />



            </cxf:jaxws-client>




        </http:outbound-endpoint>





        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />

        <mulexml:jaxb-object-to-xml-transformer
            jaxbContext-ref="xmltoobj" />
        <object-to-string-transformer />
        <append-string-transformer message="&#xD;&#xA;" />

        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />

    </sub-flow>
    <object-to-string-transformer name="ObjectToString" />
    <byte-array-to-string-transformer
        name="ByteArrayToString" />



    <tcp:connector name="TCP_C_L" validateConnections="false"
        receiveBufferSize="102400" sendBufferSize="102400" doc:name="TCP">
        <tcp:xml-protocol />
    </tcp:connector>



    <mulexml:jaxb-context name="myJaxbContext"
        packageNames="com.nsn.ossbss.charge_once.wsdl.entity.tis.xsd._1" />





    <mulexml:jaxb-context name="xmltoobj"
        packageNames="com.nsn.ossbss.charge_once.wsdl.entity.tis.xsd._1" />


    <flow name="NSNServiceClient" doc:name="NSN IN Unified Client Service">
        <tcp:inbound-endpoint host="localhost" port="51000"
            connector-ref="TCP_C_L" />
        <transformer ref="ByteArrayToString" />

        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
        <mulexml:jaxb-xml-to-object-transformer
            jaxbContext-ref="myJaxbContext" />

        <flow-ref name="usernameToken1" doc:name="usernameToken1" />

        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />

        <!-- <default-exception-strategy> <choice> 
        <when evaluator="groovy" expression='payload.getException().getClass().getName().equals("com.nsn.ossbss.charge_once.wsdl.entity.tis.wsdl._1.TisException")'> 
            <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" /> <object-to-string-transformer/> 
            <append-string-transformer message="&#xD;&#xA;" /> <vm:outbound-endpoint 
            path="error.notification"/> </when> </choice> </default-exception-strategy> -->



        <catch-exception-strategy>

            <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />

            <transformer ref="ByteArrayToString" />


            <append-string-transformer message="&#xD;&#xA;" />
            <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />




        </catch-exception-strategy>




        <!-- <auto-transformer returnClass="com.nsn.ossbss.charge_once.wsdl.entity.tis.wsdl._1.TisException"/> -->






        <!-- <custom-exception-strategy class="com.nsn.ossbss.charge_once.wsdl.entity.tis.wsdl._1.TisException"> 
            <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" /> </custom-exception-strategy> -->

    </flow>




    <flow name="SecurityClients" doc:name="SecurityClients">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
            host="localhost" port="63080" path="client" doc:name="HTTP Inbound Endpoint" />
        <set-payload
            value="#[message.inboundProperties['http.query.params']['name']]"
            doc:name="Set payload with 'name' query param" />
        <set-variable variableName="clientType"
            value="#[message.inboundProperties['http.query.params']['clientType']]"
            doc:name="Set clientType" />
        <choice doc:name="Choice">
            <when expression="#[clientType == 'unsecure']">
                <processor-chain>
                    <flow-ref name="unsecure" doc:name="Invoke unsecure sub-flow" />
                </processor-chain>
            </when>
            <!--<when expression="#[clientType == 'usernameToken']"> <processor-chain> 
                <flow-ref name="usernameToken1" doc:name="usernameToken1" /> </processor-chain> 
                </when> -->
            <when expression="#[clientType == 'usernameTokenSigned']">
                <processor-chain>
                    <flow-ref name="usernameTokenSigned" doc:name="Invoke usernameToken Signed sub-flow" />
                </processor-chain>
            </when>
            <when expression="#[clientType == 'usernameTokenEncrypted']">
                <processor-chain>
                    <flow-ref name="usernameTokenEncrypted" doc:name="Invoke usernameToken Encrypted sub-flow" />
                </processor-chain>
            </when>
            <when expression="#[clientType == 'samlToken']">
                <processor-chain>
                    <flow-ref name="samlToken" doc:name="Invoke samlToken sub-flow" />
                </processor-chain>
            </when>
            <when expression="#[clientType == 'samlTokenSigned']">
                <processor-chain>
                    <flow-ref name="samlTokenSigned" doc:name="Invoke samlToken Signed sub-flow" />
                </processor-chain>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <processor-chain>
                    <set-payload value="Client type is not supported"
                        doc:name="Client type is not supported" />
                </processor-chain>
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
        <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="text/plain"
            doc:name="Set response Content-Type" />
        <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
            <set-payload value="There has been an Error processing the request"
                doc:name="Set Payload" />
            <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="text/plain"
                doc:name="Set response Content-Type" />
        </catch-exception-strategy>



    </flow>
    <sub-flow name="unsecure" doc:name="unsecure">
        <cxf:jaxws-client operation="greet"
            serviceClass="com.mulesoft.mule.example.security.Greeter" doc:name="Unsecure SOAP client"
            doc:description="Unsecure SOAP client" />
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
            host="localhost" port="63081" path="services/unsecure" doc:name="Invoke unsecure Web Service" />
    </sub-flow>
    <!-- <sub-flow name="usernameToken" doc:name="usernameToken"> <cxf:jaxws-client 
        operation="greet" serviceClass="com.mulesoft.mule.example.security.Greeter" 
        doc:name="UsernameToken SOAP client"> <cxf:ws-security> <cxf:ws-config> <cxf:property 
        key="action" value="UsernameToken Timestamp"/> <cxf:property key="user" value="joe"/> 
        <cxf:property key="passwordCallbackClass" value="com.mulesoft.mule.example.security.PasswordCallback"/> 
        </cxf:ws-config> </cxf:ws-security> </cxf:jaxws-client> <http:outbound-endpoint 
        exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="63081" path="services/username" 
        doc:name="Invoke usernameToken Web Service"/> </sub-flow> -->
    <sub-flow name="usernameTokenSigned" doc:name="usernameTokenSigned">
        <cxf:jaxws-client operation="greet"
            serviceClass="com.mulesoft.mule.example.security.Greeter" doc:name="UsernameToken Signed SOAP client">
            <cxf:ws-security>
                <cxf:ws-config>
                    <cxf:property key="action" value="UsernameToken Signature Timestamp" />
                    <cxf:property key="signaturePropFile" value="wssecurity.properties" />
                    <cxf:property key="user" value="joe" />
                    <cxf:property key="passwordCallbackClass"
                        value="com.mulesoft.mule.example.security.PasswordCallback" />
                </cxf:ws-config>
            </cxf:ws-security>
        </cxf:jaxws-client>
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
            host="localhost" port="63081" path="services/signed"
            doc:name="Invoke usernameToken Signed Web Service" />
    </sub-flow>
    <sub-flow name="usernameTokenEncrypted" doc:name="usernameTokenEncrypted">
        <cxf:jaxws-client operation="greet"
            serviceClass="com.mulesoft.mule.example.security.Greeter" doc:name="UsernameToken Encrypted SOAP client">
            <cxf:ws-security>
                <cxf:ws-config>
                    <cxf:property key="action" value="UsernameToken Timestamp Encrypt" />
                    <cxf:property key="encryptionPropFile" value="wssecurity.properties" />
                    <cxf:property key="user" value="joe" />
                    <cxf:property key="encryptionUser" value="joe" />
                    <cxf:property key="passwordCallbackClass"
                        value="com.mulesoft.mule.example.security.PasswordCallback" />
                </cxf:ws-config>
            </cxf:ws-security>
        </cxf:jaxws-client>
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
            host="localhost" port="63081" path="services/encrypted"
            doc:name="Invoke usernameToken Encrypted Web Service" />
    </sub-flow>
    <sub-flow name="samlToken" doc:name="samlToken">
        <cxf:jaxws-client operation="greet"
            serviceClass="com.mulesoft.mule.example.security.Greeter" doc:name="SAMLToken SOAP client">
            <cxf:ws-security>
                <cxf:ws-config>
                    <cxf:property key="action" value="SAMLTokenUnsigned Timestamp" />
                    <cxf:property key="samlPropFile" value="saml.properties" />
                    <cxf:property key="samlCallbackClass"
                        value="com.mulesoft.mule.example.security.SAMLCallbackHandler" />
                </cxf:ws-config>
            </cxf:ws-security>
        </cxf:jaxws-client>
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
            host="localhost" port="63081" path="services/saml" doc:name="Invoke SAMLToken Web Service" />
    </sub-flow>
    <sub-flow name="samlTokenSigned" doc:name="samlTokenSigned">
        <cxf:jaxws-client operation="greet"
            serviceClass="com.mulesoft.mule.example.security.Greeter" doc:name="SAMLToken Signed SOAP client">
            <cxf:ws-security>
                <cxf:ws-config>
                    <cxf:property key="action" value="SAMLTokenSigned" />
                    <cxf:property key="samlPropFile" value="saml.properties" />
                    <cxf:property key="signatureKeyIdentifier" value="DirectReference" />
                    <cxf:property key="user" value="joe" />
                    <cxf:property key="passwordCallbackClass"
                        value="com.mulesoft.mule.example.security.PasswordCallback" />
                    <cxf:property key="samlCallbackClass"
                        value="com.mulesoft.mule.example.security.SAMLCallbackHandler" />
                </cxf:ws-config>
            </cxf:ws-security>
        </cxf:jaxws-client>
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
            host="localhost" port="63081" path="services/signedsaml"
            doc:name="Invoke SAMLToken Signed Web Service" />
    </sub-flow>

</mule>
```

The first sub flow usernameToken1 is calling the Web service which i deployed on apache camel , I just mentioned in the question above the exception class which has been raised.

Kindly let me know your feedback,

Comment: Could you share the flow configuration as well?

Comment: Please some one to answer i have added flow configuration ?

Comment: Ok, if I understand correctly you want to trap the exception in the catch-exception-strategy and crete the soap to send back to the client in there?

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are having is that by the time the Payload reaches the exception strategy block, the Message has already been consumed by the jaxws-client and you cannot get hold of it anymore.

What you could do is have the jaxws client outside of the outbound endpoint (right before). After the outbound endpoint you'll have the Soap Message. You can check if it was an exception or not, merely by checking the http status. If the status is an error, you can transform the message to string and store it in a variable. Once the message reaches the client on the way back, it's going to interpret the Soap message and throw the exception that it's going to be handled by the exception strategy block. Inside the exception you can read the variable where you are storing the Soap Fault and do whatever you want with it.

I know it is a very cumbersome solution, but it's the only one I can think of. The problem as I said before, is that HTTP receives a stream back from the service, and that stream is then consumed by the jaxws client before unmarshalling and throwing the exception. The only way to preserve the Soap Fault would be if Mule serializes the input every time, which can be very expensive.

HTH, 
Eva